# Blender 2.74 exporting custom normals without applying split normals modifier

Tags: python, normals

Blender finally added the possibility to use custom normals in version 2.74. YAY.
I've been playing with them to export and import a custom file format.

For example: I created the custom normals for a mesh, then call the calculate split normals and tessfaces methods

```
C.active_object.data.calc_normals_split()
C.active_object.data.update(calc_edges=True, calc_tessface=True)
```

and I can see the custom normals I expected

```
Vector(C.active_object.data.tessfaces[0].normal)
Vector(C.active_object.data.tessfaces[0].split_normals[0])
```

But if I try to use the **Set Split Normals** Modifier to create the normals, and even thou I can see the new normals working in the 3Dview, I can't find a ways to access those normals without appliying the modifier.

Can it be done?
How can access the new normals data without applying the modifier?

Comment: What about getting them from `obj.to_mesh(scene=bpy.context.scene, apply_modifiers=True, settings='PREVIEW')` then freeing the mesh after usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jerryno said, from python you can only get modifiers’ results by applying them into a temp mesh (using [`Object.to_mesh()`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_2/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh)), there is no reason for 'EditNormals' modifier to behave differently.

You can also have a look at some official exporters supporting 'apply modifier' feature (like e.g. .obj exporter), that’s what they are doing.